# Como atribuir um valor a um enum com notação binária?

Tags: c#, enums, sintaxe, declaração-de-variável, números-binários

Para trabalhar com números hexadecimais, basta adicionar `0x` na frente do numero, desta forma:

```
var numeroHexa = 0xff1120;
```

O mesmo vale para numeros octais, adicionando o `0`:

```
var numeroOct = 037;
```

Mas como faz para declarar numeros binários?

```
var numeroBin = ??00101
```

Vou usar isso para melhorar os cálculos com operadores bitwise, minha intensão é: evitar ficar comentando o valor binário de cada enum:

```
public enum Direction
{
    None = 0,   //0000
    Left = 1,   //0001
    Right = 2,  //0010
    Up = 4,     //0100
    Down = 8,   //1000
}
```

E sim declarar diretamente cada valor

```
public enum Direction
{
    None = ??0000
    Left = ??0001
    Right = ??0010
    Up = ??0100
    Down = ??1000
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Considerando a resposta do NULL sobre a inexistência de binários literais, sugiro usar o seguinte para melhorar a legibilidade do `enum`:

```
public enum Direction
{
    None = 0,      //0000
    Left = 1,      //0001
    Right = 1<<1,  //0010
    Up = 1<<2,     //0100
    Down = 1<<3,   //1000
}
```

Comment: Era algo desse tipo que eu estava procurando. Acho muito melhor dizer que `Down` é "3 bits descocados" do que simplesmente o número mágico `8`. Obrg.

Comment: E para quem achar que isto é ineficiente: a otimização do compilador resolve essa questão.

Answer (score 10):

O [C# 7 tem sintaxe para representação binária nativa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29#Versions). Você poderá usar:

```
int x = 0b0111_0100;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/BinaryNotation.cs).

Pode usar até separadores para facilitar a leitura. Os separadores podem ser usados nas demais representações numéricas também.

[Fonte](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/215).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.0/binary-literals/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **Github** para futura referência](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/BinaryLiterals.cs).

Answer (score 4):

Não é possível pra declarar literais binários no `C#`. O que você consegue fazer é um parse duma string para o formato binário usando `Convert.ToInt32`, como pode ser visto [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246832/c-sharp-binary-constants-representation?lq=1) e [aqui](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a698316f-4c35-4a5d-8175-621d5a53ee3e/how-to-represent-binary-number-directly-in-c?forum=csharplanguage).

```
int binario = Convert.ToInt32("0100", 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Trabalhando um pouco com os `DLLImport` para assemblies da Microsoft, percebi que eles usam uma notação para enuns `[Flag]` muito eficiente, simplesmente usando valores hexadecimais:

```
public enum Direction
{
    None = 0x1,   //1
    Left = 0x2,   //2
    Right = 0x4,  //4
    Up = 0x8,     //8
    Down = 0x10,   //16
}
```

#### Exemplo de uso: [link](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums.CREDUI_FLAGS)

Sendo que o numero `0x10` representa `16`, e assim por diante, é possível continuar a numeração:

```
0x20 == 32
0x40 == 64
0x80 == 128
0x100 == 256
0x200 == 512
0x400 == 1024
0x800 == 2048
0x1000 == 4096
...
```

Quer conferir? Basta abrir a ferramenta de desenvolvedor do navegador (geralmente `F12`) e colar os valores.

Comment: Só não faz a menor diferença usar hexadecimal ou decimal, isto só importa para a sintaxe. E o que você queria é binário.

Comment: Sim, exatamente, tanto que a resposta certa ainda é aquela que usa o operador `<<`. Só coloquei essa resposta pra complementar e enriquecer o post mesmo.