# Quais as diferenças mais relevantes entre C# e Java?

Tags: java, c#

Queria saber quais as diferenças mais relevantes que eu deva saber que existem entre essas duas linguagens. Por que estou perguntando isso aqui? Porque normalmente no meu dia-a-dia quando faço essa pergunta, meus colegas sempre demonstram um "favoritismo" em relação a uma dessas linguagens, apesar de não ter sido essa minha pergunta a eles.

O que é do meu conhecimento é que são linguagens semelhantes. O C# me atrai por causa de sua IDE, o Visual Studio, e o Java por sua vez me atrai por causa da proximidade com o Android e por estar a mais tempo no mercado.

OBS.: De preferência, respostas de pessoas que trabalharam com as **duas linguagens**.

Comment: Discussão no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4801/101

Comment: Com o crescimento do C# acompanhado das inovações do .NET Core, ASP.NET CORE, Blazor, Razor e afins. Sem sombra dúvida minha escolha pessoal é o C#.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

De fato quem trabalha só com uma será tendencioso para ela.

Realmente ambas são muito parecidas, mas a cultura em volta delas é muito diferente. Por exemplo, Java tenta ser mais explícita, C# tenta ser mais concisa. Mas é muito comum algumas pessoas pregarem a cultura do Java em C# (é incrível como elas chegam falar em cultura C# quando na verdade estão falando de práticas comuns em Java que foram importadas por algumas pessoas que não entendem a diferença).

Java tem uma comunidade mais ativa publicamente. Para o bem ou para o mal. Em alguns mercados possui mais vagas abertas, o que não significa que existam mais posições. Afinal em certas culturas é mais comum trocar de emprego que em outras. Nada muito diferente, mas Java é um pouco mais abrangente em algumas coisas, porém mais dispersa também, é muito comum a duplicação de esforços, competição de ferramentas (que pode ser bom ou ruim) e maneiras diferentes de fazer a mesma coisa. Isso tem mudado um pouco.

## Licença e propriedade

A Microsoft não é dona do C#, ela só criou a linguagem, a propriedade é da [.NET Foundation](https://dotnetfoundation.org/), então ela não é de domínio público, mas também não é de uma empresa, é quase de domínio de público, é até melhor porque há uma responsável (o domínio público tem implicações jurídicas ruins).

A Oracle é dona do Java, tem um histórico de processar quem adota suas tecnologias, seja pela Sun com o Java, seja pela Oracle mesmo. Atualmente (ou em passado em recente, sei lá) a Google está com problemas porque perdeu um processo que ela não pode usar mais o Java sem pagar fortunas e ainda terá que pagar pelo tempo que já usou. Espero que isso se reverta em segunda instância porque muda tudo no setor e prejudicará a todos, mas já deu para perceber que o produto não está em boas mãos. Não adianta o código fonte ser aberto se a tecnologia como um todo ser proprietária e quem a adota pode ser processado.

Alguns passos foram dados para Java ser um projeto mais aberto.

## [Paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101)

Java preza mais pela orientação a objeto embora seja essencialmente imperativo e agora está indo um pouquinho para o funcional.

C# marca de forma mais clara seu multi-paradigmatismo, embora se declare (ou declarava) orientada a objeto, ela tem muito forte o imperativo-procedural e viola a orientação a objeto quando isso for pragmático. Embora não seja uma linguagem essencialmente funcional tem partes desse paradigma muito forte e a evolução da linguagem remete a ser cada vez mais funcional. Ela também adere bem a orientação a contratos, eventos, padrões, é um pouco mais fácil ser orientada a aspectos (agora mais ainda com geração de código e com *interceptors*), é um pouco mais declarativa, enfim, ela abraça mais estilos. E ela dá muito valor à performance.

## Ecossistema

Além da linguagem que possuem especificidades que agradam mais uma pessoa do que outra, o ecossistema faz diferença, sem dúvida. Não vou entrar muito nisso para não ficar longo.

Não é só o C# que possui bom IDE, Java também. Muitos gostam do [Eclipse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) e tem nele, ou em *plugins* para ele, coisas que eu gostaria de ver no VS. Acho o VS pelado e um pouco inferior, mas quando junta com [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) e outros *plugins*, ele fica ótimo mesmo. [O VS "completo" é gratuito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40609/101). Nem todos bons *plugins* são. Tem outras opções muito boas. A edição Enterprise é algo extraordinário, mesmo que nem todos precisem de tudo aquilo.

É comum ter mais ferramentas e bibliotecas em Java do que em C#, especialmente gratuitos e de código aberto. Mas isso está mudando pouco a pouco.

Nem sempre ter vários significa boa coisa. Pode significar que nenhum atende bem as necessidades. Ter muitas escolhas pode ser angustiante, ou ser a solução ideal. Por exemplo, Java tem "trocentos" *frameworks* para web. Claro que poucos são bem usados e recomendados. C# atualmente só recomenda o ASP.NET MVC (na versão Core) e qualquer outra é considerado legado. mas ultimamente passou ter variações dele, ainda sendo o mesmo produto, há flexibilidade de estilos para atender várias demandas. Talvez seja o melhor dos dois mundos.

Quase tudo o que é reconhecidamente bom em Java alguém faz um *port* para C# ou algo inspirado no que existe para Java. É raro o programador ficar na mão. O contrário também é verdadeiro, mas em menor grau, para o bem ou para o mal.

Existem bibliotecas, padrão ou não, para Java que são melhores, e o mesmo pode ser dito para o C#. Não saberia pesar qual sai ganhando aqui, e acho mais secundário. Tem soluções para tudo em ambas.

## Plataformas

Outro ponto é que o C# roda em todas as <strike>3</strike>2 plataformas *mobile mainstream*. Java só roda em uma (agora roda em outra, mas não tão bem), e melhor, claro - mas não é bem Java puro e o mais moderno. Há tentativas para mudar isso, logo esta deficiência será sanada, se já não foi, mas não ouço falar de Java no iOS, mesmo que exista solução as pessoas não parecem usar. Fora Swift e Kotlin, parece que Java é usado ainda um pouco em uma das plataformas e C# se tornou a linguagem padrão quando quer as duas plataformas de forma nativa.

Nas plataformas desktop o C# agora roda com a mesma qualidade em todas. O Java ainda é arredio ao Windows (pode ter melhorado em alguns pontos). É verdade que o C# não vai bem em GUI multi-plataforma - tem opções mas não é o ideal (melhorou com o [MAUI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455179/101)). Mas é bem questionável o quanto o Java faz isso com sucesso. Ambas possuem opções de GUI confusas e legadas.

## Evolução

C# começou copiando muito o Java, isso era motivo de piada. Hoje tem ocorrido muito o contrário.

C# abriu o código de forma mais livre e mais completa antes do Java. Os tendenciosos não reconhecem isso porque um ponto que eles consideravam forte era a liberdade que o Java tinha, o que nunca foi essa verdade toda.

C# começou antes melhorar a modularização e diminuição da dependência do CLR padrão. JVM tem propostas para isso (acho que agora tem opção assim).

Aliás, várias melhorias do Java se deram quando o C# surgiu mostrando que vinha com diversas coisas mais modernas, desde construções da linguagem até melhorias de desempenho. A melhor coisa que aconteceu para o Java foi o surgimento do C#.

C# foi ficando melhor a cada versão, Java está correndo atrás. Em alguns casos ela até está fazendo melhor que o C#. Em geral quem faz depois, faz melhor porque aprendeu com o erro de quem foi pioneiro. Há casos que não dá mais para arrumar sem tornar o código incompatível, tem erros que cometidos no começo não podem ser consertados. O C# já sofre com isso também. Eu acho que o C# era para ser melhor do que é. É reconhecido que eles tiveram a oportunidade de consertar mais erros do Java do que fizeram, certamente muitas características funcionais seriam melhores se a linguagem tivesse esperado uns 2 ou 3 anos para ser lançada.

Hoje ambas são bem maduras.

## Item por item

Já adianto que na maior parte dos casos a escolha será feita por gosto ou por algum aspecto político e não técnico. Ambas tem defeitos e qualidades, ambas resolvem bem qualquer tipo de problema que este tipo de linguagem pode resolver, afinal elas são do mesmo paradigma. Ambas rodam essencialmente nos mesmos lugares, com poucas diferenças. Para web ambas são muito boas, uma com vários *frameworks* e outras com menos, porém mais bem estabilizado.

Fiz uma revisão considerando Java 20 e C# 12 (algumas são especulações).

#### Ambiente

- C# tem pregado o uso em um ambiente único, parece que Java tem buscado esse caminho também. Antes ambas tinham várias formas de executar seus códigos e apesar de ter algumas vantagens era bem confuso. Java tem muitos fornecedores e isso pode ser complicado. O Java que roda em certos ambientes não é o mesmo Java que roda em outros, ou seja, eles prometeram algo que não puderam cumprir.
- Java tem um ambiente um pouco melhor desenvolvido, o [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) e o [coletor de lixo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255769/101) e outros mecanismos são mais avançados. Por deficiências na linguagem eles precisam ser para não ficar pra trás. C# tem melhorado, mas de forma mais lenta por não ser tão necessário. Java tem mais opções alternativas.
- É difícil afirmar qual é mais rápida, depende de cada caso, de como se faz os testes. É possível provar casos específicos, mas não no geral. O que pode valer em uma versão pode não ser verdade em outra. Mas em cada versão C# tem ficado melhor e cada vez é mais raro Java ter alguma vantagem.
- O [consumo de memória do Java é brutalmente maior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52517/101). Não vou entrar em detalhes, cabe perguntas específicas, já tem alguma coisa no site.
- C# possui muito mais [metadados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata_(CLI)) que Java.
- Ambas possuem forte [reflexão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming), mas o [jeito de usar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13089/101) é bem diferente.
- A [serialização](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) é feita de forma bem diferente (isso andou mudando e ainda mudará mais, C# tem/terá uma forma fantástica).
- O [sistema de segurança do ambiente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Access_Security) é mais completo no C# (no .NET Framework).
- O AOT do C# já está ficando muito bom, Java está se preparando.
- Java tem *virtual threads*.

#### Tipagem

- Em C# tudo deriva de `Object`, em Java os primitivos não.
- Java ainda não permite criar seus próprios tipos por valor (`structs`). Java só possui os poucos tipos primitivos prontos. [Dizem que vai ter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Valhalla_(Java_language)) (há anos, nunca entregam), não sei o quanto poderá se integrar bem ao sistema de tipos atual.
- Por isso não tem tipos por referência que são alocados na pilha.
- Java não permite criar tipos anônimos.
- C# prefere que os tipos sejam por valor sempre que faça sentido, como o `DateTime`. Java coloca quase tudo como referência, que causa maior consumo de memória, processamento e pressão no GC.
- Java não possui tipos numéricos sem sinal.
- Java não pode ligar e desligar a [verificação de estouro numérico](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) na linguagem.
- Java pode garantir que o comportamento do [ponto flutuante seja o mesmo em todas as plataformas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp) (há consequências negativas).
- Java só possui o tipo [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) na biblioteca e só na forma longa (ocupa mais memória). Existem alguns outros tipos que não existem na linguagem.
- C# possui [*arrays* retangulares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (multidimensionais).
- <strike>C# não tem facilidades para fazer *substring* aproveitando a *string* já existente.</strike> Isso causa vazamento de memória. [Java abandonou a prática](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4513622), mas o custo de ter a facilidade permaneceu. C# agora tem facilidade mais correta que Java tentou adotar.
- Java não tem [classes puramente estáticas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas pode acessar membros estáticos diretamente pela instância enquanto C# só através de da classe (tem vantagens e desvantagens).
- Os `enum`s do Java são [mais orientados a objeto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13445186/221800) e [mais fortemente tipados](https://stackoverflow.com/q/469287/221800). Embora [dê para simulá-los no C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1376312/221800), é ruim e o que a linguagem usa de fato, é pior que do Java em funcionalidade, mas melhor em eficiência. C# terá algo bem mais poderoso.
- Java não pode [passar tipos "primitivos" por referência](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref). Tem que encaixotar para fazer isso.
- Java não tem [tipos anuláveis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), dá para simular, mas não é conveniente e a biblioteca não lida com isso então não teria muito valor.
- Java não tem [tipos e métodos parciais](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- Java não permite mais de uma classe pública por arquivo.
- Java não tem como ter [tipos dinâmicos opcionais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12728/101) que [só serão verificados em tempo de execução](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Isso ajuda com interoperabilidade com outras linguagens e COM, por exemplo.
- C# possui [tuplas reais com membros nomeados](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/347) permitindo retorno de múltiplos resultados em métodos, desconstrução e outros usos.
- C# tem [*pattern matching*](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/patterns.md) bem poderoso e já avançado e melhora em cada versão. Java está soltando isso aos poucos.
- C# e Java estão implantando *records*, C# está mais avançado e tem até `record struct`.
- C# está caminhando para ter *roles* e *extensions*, mas já tem algumas melhorias para dar mais semântica aos tipos e melhorar os contratos.
- C# pode ter aliases de qualquer tipo.
- C# permite usar *array* com alocação *inline* (como se fosse por valor).
- C# deveria incorporar uma nova biblioteca de datas como Java fez.

#### Orientação a objeto

- Java tem os [métodos virtuais por *default*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/814934/221800). C# escolheu não ter para facilitar a performance e encapsulamento. Poderia ter ido além e ter deixado a classe selada por *default* também, perdeu essa oportunidade.
- Java tem classes escondidas e opcionalmente seladas com escolha do que pode herdar, que é bem interessante, C# deveria ter.
- Em Java o *override* é implícito (há sintaxe para ajudar o compilador) ao passo que em C# precisa ser explícito.
- Há diferenças de como corre o *method hiding* nas duas. O C# possui o `new` para explicitar isso.
- Java não chama [finalizadores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalizer) herdados.
- Java não permite criar (sobrecarregar) operadores para os tipos. Com isso [sobrecarrega-se](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading) :P a sintaxe do código. C# fez isso de uma forma melhor que do C++. O uso errado do recurso no C++ fez o Java não ter isso. Mas engenheiros devem encontrar solução, não abandonar o projeto. Inclui aí operadores de *cast* implícito e explícito.
- Java não tem [propriedades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming)) na linguagem, usa-se convenções.
- Com isso Java não possui [indexadores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é um operador sobrecarregado que funciona como uma propriedade.
- C# não possui [classes internas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) que é o que Java usa para simular a falta de delegados. Muito menos tem classes internas anônimas, até existe como aninhar classes, mas isto é feito de forma estática.
- Java não tem [métodos de extensão](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- C# não pode declarar [campos estáticos finais na interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/320588/221800), mas está previsto (tem parcialmente agora).
- <strike>C# não tem [métodos *default* dentro de interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)</strike>. Tem que criar a interface e o método de extensão. Agora tem.
- C# permite [implementar um método especificamente para uma interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- Há diferença na ordem de inicialização de objetos e tipos.
- Java não tem [inicializadores de objetos e coleções](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

#### Métodos

- Java não possui parâmetros (*default*) e [argumentos opcionais/nomeados](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- C# não permite que os [parâmetros originalmente mutáveis sejam declarados como imutáveis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500508/221800) naquele contexto.
- Java não possui [métodos condicionais](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- Java não possui [funções locais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130191/101).
- Java não permite a [passagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82630/101) e [retorno](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/118) de tipos por valor como referência. C# já tem até campos por referência.
- C# possui [sintaxe simplificada para qualquer método de uma linha](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7881), incluindo propriedades, semelhante à *lambda*.
- C# tem *primary constructors*

#### Exceções

- C# não possui [*checked exceptions*](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129). Java é essencialmente a única linguagem que implementa isso. Mesmo entre os Javeiros não há consenso se é bom tê-las.
- Java não possui [*filter exceptions*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29390908/221800).
- Java tende a usar a exceção para controle de fluxo normal, C# evita isso, até porque seu mecanismo, quando gera exceção, é mais lento, algumas pessoas importam essa cultura do Java, mas isso é errado.
- Em Java a exceção só pode ser um *statement* ao contrário de C# que [pode ser uma expressão](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/throwexpr.md).

#### Funcional

- O uso de [*lambdas* do Java é bem mais limitado ao do C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/786540/Lambda-Expressions-in-Csharp-and-Java). Melhoraram a sintaxe, mas não semântica. Isso foi o motivo do C# existir, mas não vou falar da briga entre a Sun e Microsoft aqui. Em C# melhora em cada versão.
- Java não possui [eventos](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Tem que implementar o padrão Observer na mão, o que pode dar mais flexibilidade. Obviamente é possível fazer o mesmo em C#, se precisar.
- Java não possui [árvores de expressão](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- Java não possui [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Agora tem algo que ajuda um pouco ([Java Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)), mas longe da facilidade total que o LINQ oferece. Vi coisas bem esquisitas em Java.
- Java não possui [geradores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44293/101) (iteradores).
- Java possui só uma forma mais limitada de [inferência de tipo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference).

#### Módulos

- Todo o funcionamento de módulos de ambos é muito diferente. Java possui [pacotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package), C# possui [*namespaces*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101) e [*assemblies*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_(CLI)). O primeiro é para separar os tipos em grupos de nomes, de famílias. O outro funciona de forma semelhante ao pacote do java, mas não possui uma nomenclatura semântica na linguagem. A organização é mais flexível e não depende de como está implantado.
- Com isso a visibilidade do C# pode ser restrita de forma mais granular.
- Em C# os *assemblies* podem ser amigos de outros e permitir acesso extra.
- Java não pode mudar o nome do pacote importado (alias) para facilitar o uso.
- C# permite importação global.
- C# permite não só não usar um *namespace*, mas até mesmo uma classe é opcional.

#### Operadores

- Java não tem operadores para ajudar com nulidade ([`??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e [`?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)).
- Java não tem o operador [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- C# possui dois tipos de [*cast* explícito](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

#### Facilidades extras

- Java não possui [diretivas de processamento condicional](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (`#if`). C# não possui um pré-processador, é integrado na linguagem e é limitado em relação ao que dá para fazer no C/C++.
- C# tem mais facilidades para trabalhar com [assincronicidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101), inclusive na linguagem.
- Java pode ter [métodos sincronizados](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncrgb.html) pela linguagem, C# só pode ter blocos (ainda que possa ser o método todo) ou com o uso de bibliotecas ou anotações. No fundo parece ser só uma diferença sintática.
- A genericidade do C# não usa [*type erasure*](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111211139/https://www.beust.com/weblog/2011/07/29/erasure-vs-reification/), o que é uma grande ajuda para performance e uso geral. Há uma semântica de genericidade, enquanto que no Java é só um truque do compilador. Me parece que a restrição de variância ocorre no local certo.
- C# permite mais [usos, variedade de tipos e restrições](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) nos tipos genéricos.
- Java não pode fazer [interpolação de *string*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Nem tem [*verbatim strings*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (passou ter alguma coisa).
- Java não tenta simplificar a sintaxe de muitas coisas, especialmente de métodos de uma linha que em C# pode usar a sintaxe de *lambda*, mesmo não sendo.
- Java não suporta [`goto`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101), apesar de tê-lo como palavra-chave.
- C# pode ser compilado em tempo de execução, tem um sistema de *scripting* e um REPL. O [.NET Compiler Platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101) é um avanço para a linguagem, biblioteca e para facilitar o aumento de todo o ecossistema de ferramentas. Java permite alguma coisa nesse sentido de forma bem mais limitada.
- Java não permite código [*unsafe*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) o que dificulta a interoperabilidade com outras linguagens e performance em algumas situações. Java possui [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) para interoperabilidade. É raro quem ache isto uma boa solução. Alguns acham ruim permitir ter código inseguro na linguagem e que isto faz a linguagem ser menos segura, mas está longe de ser verdade, a pessoa precisa entender melhor o recursos para criticar. Eu nunca usei de fato o *unsafe*, mas adoro saber que ele está lá quando eu precisar. Java tem um projeto para melhorar isso, mas não terá como ser tão bom pela limitação da linguagem atual. Tem algumas melhorias mais recentes. C# está melhorando cada vez mais.
- Então Java não pode usar [ponteiros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code#pointer-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), nem gerenciados em áreas específicas, como são em C# em casos pontuais onde eles são mais adequados. E C# tem introduzido mecanismos cada vez melhores onde usa a vantagem do ponteiro sem ter a desvantagem.
- Java possui [*soft/phantom references*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9809074/221800).
- Java não faz otimização de *tail recursion*. [C# faz em x64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15864670/221800) (não sei se já tem em x86 ou ARM).
- C# permite representação de [literais binários e uso de separadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13723/101) para melhor legibilidade.
- C# tem o `switch` com expressão, Java está começando ter.
- C# tem um mecanismo de assincronicidade que é referência no mercado, Java promete que terá algum mecanismo que servirá para o mesmo propósito.
- Java parece estar um passo adiante no uso de NVM. Isso pode ser ruim porque ainda não se sabe a melhor forma de usar essa nova tecnologia.
- C# tem geradores de código que está ajudando revolucionar alguns códigos.
- C# tem feito uma quantidade imensa de pequenas melhorias sintáticas e algumas semânticas, Java vai bem mais devagar nisso, tem feito muito *preview* antes de lançar algo.

## Conclusão

Não vou perder tempo com pequenas diferenças sintáticas. Também não vou entrar em detalhes quando uma implementa algo um pouco melhor que a outra, mas sem muita relevância. Entrando no campo da opinião, acho o guia de estilo do Java pior do que do C#.

Tudo que dá para fazer em uma linguagem dá para fazer na outra, e nem é tão diferente assim entre elas, mas as muitas pequenas diferenças acabam sendo importante no final.

Você pode achar que fui tendencioso por mostrar um monte de coisa que o C# tem e o Java não, mas é assim mesmo. Java é uma linguagem mais simples, isso tem seu mérito, mas ela é simples de aprender, nem tanto de usar.

Eu vejo muitas vezes as pessoas dizerem "que bom que minha linguagem preferida **não** tem o recurso tal", só que elas adoram quando a linguagem coloca aquilo depois, e acham até que ficou melhor que a outra. Outros ficam na teimosia, esse tipo de atitude não é boa para profissionais, ninguém deveria se apaixonar por tecnologias.

O Jon Skeet é reconhecidamente muito bom nas duas linguagens e trabalha com ambas. Se ele pudesse escolher qual usar integralmente, claramente seria o C#. Minha resposta foi muito baseada na [resposta dele](https://stackoverflow.com/a/295248/221800) e de outros no SO.

O Neal Gafter esteve muito envolvido na criação e evolução do Java por mais de 10 anos e agora está quase igualando esse tempo envolvido com a evolução do C#, e [me parece que ele prefere o C#](https://www.infoq.com/articles/neal-gafter-on-java).

Mais referências [aqui](https://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/) e [aqui](http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html). Na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java).

Aceito sugestões/edições. Posso ter esquecido alguma coisa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Bem esclarecedor.
Me ajudou a orientar meus estudos.
Na faculdade estou aprendendo C#, mas minha intenção é Java. Porém, com estas informações deu sentir que não as duas linguagens não tem tantos antagonismo. E como dito ao final, é importante entender a usabilidade de cada uma, e não ser necessariamente fanático por uma e execrar a outra.