# O que há de errado com o Java?

Tags: java, design-de-linguagem

Quais são os problemas e limitações do Java?

Pode malhar o Java, mas com ponderação e conhecimento de causa, sem se deixar levar pelo emocional. De preferência citando qual alternativa se propõe melhor que o comportamento correspondente no Java e porquê.

Espero que a pergunta seja construtiva.

Comment: Java pode causar hipertensão, palpitação, perda de sono e dependência. Ah, você está falando do Java da finada Sun, não desse [Java](https://driftaway.coffee/coffee-called-java/)... Foi mal.

Comment: É ampla demais porque Java tem muitos problemas :p

Comment: Mas como posso especificá-los sem saber antes enumerá-los? :)

Comment: Talvez esta pergunta dê uma boa discussão no [stackunderflow, lá no reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackunderflow).

Comment: @Piovezan a Kathy Sierra, que é meio que uma "avó" do Java (ela treinava a galera na Sun que desenvolvia a plataforma) passou mais de uma década enumerando os problemas do Java em livros, blog e outras publicações. Tudo que ela escreveu deve dar umas 10 a 15 bíblias empilhadas de texto. Boa pesquisa e boa leitura.

Comment: Em tempo: como qualquer outra tecnologia, o problema do Java não é o Java em si, mas como uma multidão de pessoas o utiliza de forma errada pelos mais diversos motivos.

Comment: Isto ajuda um pouco: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110142/101. Muito do que era considerado ruim em Java não existe mais, mas sua filosofia, apesar de mudar um pouco, ainda torna o desenvolvimento um pouco tedioso. Mas é mais gosto mesmo. O ecossistema e é enorme e redundante. Fica difícil escolher o que usar. Há técnicas que se costuma usar em Java que são piores do que a linguagem em si. Ela paga o preço de ter sido desenvolvida antes da hora. Ela tem seus méritos também. Está melhorando onde pode. Tanto que agora copia tudo do C# :D C# tem seus defeitos tb. Como todas linguagens.

Comment: @Renan tem alguma referência mais específica? Algo organizado? Ou tem que sair pesquisando a esmo mesmo? Fiquei curioso.

Comment: @bigown eu não sei de nada organizado. Até porque os problemas do Java eram muito diversos e dispersos. Se alguém souber de algo, eu adoraria saber também. Até para ter mais embasamento quando for apresentar um comparativo de tecnologias pra alguém.

Comment: Isso ñ ajuda muito https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Kathy+Sierra+java+problem :)

Comment: O downvoter pode explicar o porquê do voto negativo?