# O nome do parâmetro não bate com a variável passada

Tags: java, funções, variáveis, parâmetros

```
void countdown(int max, boolean output) {
  for (int i=max; i>=0; i--)
    if (output)
      println(i);
}
void setup(){
  int top = 20;
  countdown(top, true);
}
```

Tem alguma coisa errada com a sintaxe/escrita do código acima?

O método `Countdown` é chamado com a variável `top` ao invés da variável `max`. E `Countdown` é chamado com um booleano literal, e não uma variável.

Comment: Aparentemente está tranquilo. O que te incomoda?

Comment: O método Countdown é chamado com a variável top ao invés da variável max. E Countdown é chamado com um boolean literal, e não uma variável.

Comment: Mas essa é a ideia de diferenciar parâmetros de argumentos. Leia mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32450/64969)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função é completamente independente da sua chamada. Uma das ideias por trás do conceito da função é justamente este. Função serve como uma abstração, então você só precisa saber o contrato mínimo para chamá-la e receber o que ela resultar, não precisa saber detalhes extras de como ela foi escrita para usá-la. O nome dos parâmetros não faz parte do contrato (tem linguagem que faz), você sequer precisa saber deles, mesmo que saiba não há obrigatoriedade de usar os mesmos nomes nos argumentos de chamada, até porque os argumentos aceitam quaisquer expressões da linguagem, incluindo literais ou cálculos feitos ali, não precisa usar variáveis.

O parâmetro sempre é uma variável, o argumento é sempre um valor, se ele é obtido através de uma variável é só uma coincidência.

Em Java o contrato só importa o nome da função (método) e os tipos de todos os parâmetros na ordem, além do tipo de retorno que não faz parte da [assinatura do método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101).

[Tem linguagem que permite usar o nome do parâmetro no argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110142/101), assim dando mais semântica ao que está fazendo e até permitindo usar fora de ordem e deixar alguns argumentos opcionais.

Veja [Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).